# PHP convert week number and year back to Carbon?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm using format W-Y  for weeknumber & year.

e.g. the final week of 2018 would be represented as `'52-2018'`.

But I can't get Carbon or DateTime to convert it back.

```
>>> Carbon::createFromFormat('W-Y', '01-2018')

InvalidArgumentException with message 'The format separator does not match
The separation symbol could not be found
Trailing data'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateTime::createFromFormat` (which is what Carbon extends) doesn't support the `W` formatting character, unfortunately.

The easiest way to work around this is to create a new `DateTime` (or Carbon) instance, and use the native [`setISODate`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php) method to set the year and week number:

```
$str = '01-2018';
list ($week, $year) = explode('-', $str);
$d = new DateTime;
$d->setISODate($year, $week);
```

See https://3v4l.org/g33QV

Comment: Magnificent. Thank you - saved me a refactor.

Answer (score 0):

A string of the form '01-2018' can also be converted to '2018W01' with `preg_replace`, which can then be processed directly by `DateTime` and Carbon.

```
$str = '01-2018';
$dateTime = new DateTime(preg_replace('~^(\d\d)-(\d\d\d\d)$~','$2W$1',$str));
```

While with the accepted solution we always get the current time for the date, here it is always 00:00:00.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/mo6dQ